Why can't I set max delay between pins for my FPGA?
I'm a software engineer just starting to play with FPGAs (Currently,Nexys A7 100T). I'm having a heck of a time getting the constraints to do what I want, and I can't seem to find the answers online.
I have an extremely simple circuit. It simply takes the values of the switches on the board (16 total switches... 8 for x, 8 for y, though I essentially double them in this silly example to force the synthesizer to use a DSP instead of LUTs because an 8 bit multiplier is synthesized with LUTs from my experimentation), which passes through an "ALU" to multiply x by y, and then show the resulting number in the 16 LEDs on the board.
module ALU(
    input wire [15:0] x,
    input wire [15:0] y,
    input wire [2:0] func,
    output reg [15:0] out
);
    
    always @(*) begin
        case(func)
            3'b000: out = x + y;
            3'b001: out = x & y;
            3'b010: out = x ^ y;
            3'b011: (* use_dsp = "yes" *) out = x * y;  // Use DSP block for multiplication
            default: out = x;
        endcase
    end
    
endmodule

and
module top_level (
    input wire clk,            // Clock input
    input wire [15:0] SW,      // 16 switches (for x and y)
    output reg [15:0] LED      // 16 LEDs to display the ALU result
);
    // Explicitly declare registers for x, y, and the ALU result
    reg [15:0] x_reg;
    reg [15:0] y_reg;
    reg [15:0] alu_result_reg;

    // Wire for ALU output
    wire [15:0] alu_out;

    // Assign switch inputs to the x and y registers
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        x_reg <= {SW[7:0], SW[7:0]};  // Repeat SW[7:0] to form a 16-bit input
        y_reg <= {SW[15:8], SW[15:8]}; // Repeat SW[15:8] to form a 16-bit input
    end

    // Instantiate the ALU
    ALU alu_instance (
        .x(x_reg),       // Input from x register
        .y(y_reg),       // Input from y register
        .func(3'b011),   // Set function to multiplication
        .out(alu_out)    // ALU output
    );

    // Store ALU result in alu_result_reg and update LEDs
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        alu_result_reg <= alu_out;  // Store the ALU result in a register
        LED <= alu_out;             // Update LEDs with the current ALU result
    end

endmodule

with the following schematic after synthesizing and implementing:

All I want to do is measure the time between the inputs and outputs of the ALU... SW_IBUF and P

Right now it's obviously contrived and only does multiplication, but the end goal is implementing some hardware division and making sure that the logic can finish within some amount of time.
get_pins -hierarchical in the TCL console yields
get_pins -hierarchical
LED_OBUF[0]_inst/O LED_OBUF[0]_inst/I LED_OBUF[10]_inst/O LED_OBUF[10]_inst/I LED_OBUF[11]_inst/O LED_OBUF[11]_inst/I LED_OBUF[12]_inst/O LED_OBUF[12]_inst/I LED_OBUF[13]_inst/O LED_OBUF[13]_inst/I LED_OBUF[14]_inst/O LED_OBUF[14]_inst/I LED_OBUF[15]_inst/O LED_OBUF[15]_inst/I LED_OBUF[1]_inst/O LED_OBUF[1]_inst/I LED_OBUF[2]_inst/O LED_OBUF[2]_inst/I LED_OBUF[3]_inst/O LED_OBUF[3]_inst/I LED_OBUF[4]_inst/O LED_OBUF[4]_inst/I LED_OBUF[5]_inst/O LED_OBUF[5]_inst/I LED_OBUF[6]_inst/O LED_OBUF[6]_inst/I LED_OBUF[7]_inst/O LED_OBUF[7]_inst/I LED_OBUF[8]_inst/O LED_OBUF[8]_inst/I LED_OBUF[9]_inst/O LED_OBUF[9]_inst/I SW_IBUF[0]_inst/O SW_IBUF[0]_inst/I SW_IBUF[10]_inst/O SW_IBUF[10]_inst/I SW_IBUF[11]_inst/O SW_IBUF[11]_inst/I SW_IBUF[12]_inst/O SW_IBUF[12]_inst/I SW_IBUF[13]_inst/O SW_IBUF[13]_inst/I SW_IBUF[14]_inst/O SW_IBUF[14]_inst/I SW_IBUF[15]_inst/O SW_IBUF[15]_inst/I SW_IBUF[1]_inst/O SW_IBUF[1]_inst/I SW_IBUF[2]_inst/O SW_IBUF[2]_inst/I SW_IBUF[3]_inst/O SW_IBUF[3]_inst/I SW_IBUF[4]_inst/O SW_IBUF[4]_inst/I SW_IBUF[5]_inst/O SW_IBUF[5]_inst/I SW_IBUF[6]_inst/O SW_IBUF[6]_inst/I SW_IBUF[7]_inst/O SW_IBUF[7]_inst/I SW_IBUF[8]_inst/O SW_IBUF[8]_inst/I SW_IBUF[9]_inst/O SW_IBUF[9]_inst/I alu_instance/P[0] alu_instance/P[10] alu_instance/P[11] alu_instance/P[12] alu_instance/P[13] alu_instance/P[14] alu_instance/P[15] alu_instance/P[1] alu_instance/P[2] alu_instance/P[3] alu_instance/P[4] alu_instance/P[5] alu_instance/P[6] alu_instance/P[7] alu_instance/P[8] alu_instance/P[9] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[0] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[10] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[11] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[12] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[13] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[14] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[15] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[1] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[2] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[3] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[4] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[5] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[6] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[7] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[8] alu_instance/SW_IBUF[9] alu_instance/clk_IBUF_BUFG clk_IBUF_BUFG_inst/O clk_IBUF_BUFG_inst/I clk_IBUF_inst/O clk_IBUF_inst/I alu_instance/GND/G alu_instance/GND_1/G alu_instance/VCC/P alu_instance/VCC_1/P alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[29] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[28] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[27] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[26] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[25] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[24] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[23] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[22] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[21] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[20] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[19] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[18] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[17] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[16] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[15] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[14] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[13] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[12] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[11] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[10] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[9] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[8] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[7] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[6] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[5] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[4] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[3] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[2] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[1] alu_instance/out0/ACOUT[0] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[17] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[16] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[15] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[14] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[13] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[12] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[11] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[10] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[9] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[8] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[7] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[6] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[5] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[4] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[3] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[2] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[1] alu_instance/out0/BCOUT[0] alu_instance/out0/CARRYCASCOUT alu_instance/out0/CARRYOUT[3] alu_instance/out0/CARRYOUT[2] alu_instance/out0/CARRYOUT[1] alu_instance/out0/CARRYOUT[0] alu_instance/out0/MULTSIGNOUT alu_instance/out0/OVERFLOW alu_instance/out0/PATTERNBDETECT alu_instance/out0/PATTERNDETECT alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[47] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[46] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[45] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[44] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[43] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[42] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[41] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[40] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[39] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[38] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[37] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[36] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[35] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[34] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[33] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[32] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[31] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[30] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[29] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[28] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[27] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[26] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[25] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[24] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[23] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[22] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[21] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[20] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[19] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[18] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[17] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[16] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[15] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[14] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[13] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[12] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[11] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[10] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[9] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[8] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[7] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[6] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[5] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[4] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[3] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[2] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[1] alu_instance/out0/PCOUT[0] alu_instance/out0/P[47] alu_instance/out0/P[46] alu_instance/out0/P[45] alu_instance/out0/P[44] alu_instance/out0/P[43] alu_instance/out0/P[42] alu_instance/out0/P[41] alu_instance/out0/P[40] alu_instance/out0/P[39] alu_instance/out0/P[38] alu_instance/out0/P[37] alu_instance/out0/P[36] alu_instance/out0/P[35] alu_instance/out0/P[34] alu_instance/out0/P[33] alu_instance/out0/P[32] alu_instance/out0/P[31] alu_instance/out0/P[30] alu_instance/out0/P[29] alu_instance/out0/P[28] alu_instance/out0/P[27] alu_instance/out0/P[26] alu_instance/out0/P[25] alu_instance/out0/P[24] alu_instance/out0/P[23] alu_instance/out0/P[22] alu_instance/out0/P[21] alu_instance/out0/P[20] alu_instance/out0/P[19] alu_instance/out0/P[18] alu_instance/out0/P[17] alu_instance/out0/P[16] alu_instance/out0/P[15] alu_instance/out0/P[14] alu_instance/out0/P[13] alu_instance/out0/P[12] alu_instance/out0/P[11] alu_instance/out0/P[10] alu_instance/out0/P[9] alu_instance/out0/P[8] alu_instance/out0/P[7] alu_instance/out0/P[6] alu_instance/out0/P[5] alu_instance/out0/P[4] alu_instance/out0/P[3] alu_instance/out0/P[2] alu_instance/out0/P[1] alu_instance/out0/P[0] alu_instance/out0/UNDERFLOW alu_instance/out0/ACIN[29] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[28] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[27] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[26] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[25] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[24] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[23] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[22] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[21] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[20] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[19] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[18] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[17] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[16] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[15] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[14] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[13] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[12] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[11] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[10] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[9] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[8] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[7] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[6] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[5] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[4] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[3] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[2] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[1] alu_instance/out0/ACIN[0] alu_instance/out0/ALUMODE[3] alu_instance/out0/ALUMODE[2] alu_instance/out0/ALUMODE[1] alu_instance/out0/ALUMODE[0] alu_instance/out0/A[29] alu_instance/out0/A[28] alu_instance/out0/A[27] alu_instance/out0/A[26] alu_instance/out0/A[25] alu_instance/out0/A[24] alu_instance/out0/A[23] alu_instance/out0/A[22] alu_instance/out0/A[21] alu_instance/out0/A[20] alu_instance/out0/A[19] alu_instance/out0/A[18] alu_instance/out0/A[17] alu_instance/out0/A[16] alu_instance/out0/A[15] alu_instance/out0/A[14] alu_instance/out0/A[13] alu_instance/out0/A[12] alu_instance/out0/A[11] alu_instance/out0/A[10] alu_instance/out0/A[9] alu_instance/out0/A[8] alu_instance/out0/A[7] alu_instance/out0/A[6] alu_instance/out0/A[5] alu_instance/out0/A[4] alu_instance/out0/A[3] alu_instance/out0/A[2] alu_instance/out0/A[1] alu_instance/out0/A[0] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[17] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[16] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[15] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[14] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[13] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[12] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[11] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[10] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[9] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[8] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[7] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[6] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[5] alu_instance/out0/BCIN[4] alu_instance/out0...


It seems like no matter what I try adding to the constraints file, ex. set_max_delay -from [get_pins alu_instance/SW_IBUF[*]] -to [get_pins alu_instance/P[*]] 10, I get the same kind of warning:  [Vivado 12-4739] set_max_delay:No valid object(s) found for '-from [get_pins {alu_instance/SW_IBUF[*]}]'. ["C:/fpga/ALU/constraints.xdc":11] 
Any obvious mistakes I'm making or poor assumptions / misconceptions I have about this? Is there a better way to ensure combinatorial logic executes within a clock cycle (And also using timing analysis to find out how many cycles a chunk of combinatorial logic will take)?

It is implicit in synchronous design that the logic will complete within a clock cycle. So the only constraint you need to set is the clock period itself. The synthesis tools will make sure that this constraint is met, or tell you what the maximum clock frequency is if you don't set it. Or tell you that the constraint can't be met and by how much it misses.

What if I were to add a slow operation like division to the ALU, which would likely not complete in a single clock cycle. I would then likely need to use https://docs.amd.com/r/2021.2-English/ug903-vivado-using-constraints/Multicycle-Paths... but if the pins can't be found then im not sure how I can use that either. IE. it is expected that the division will take 15 cycles (for example), and the CPU will handle this, so the fact that this path takes so long doesn't violate any constraints. Again, this is for a contrived non-pipelined simple CPU.

One would not normally add a slow combinatorial divider to a data path that is otherwise quite fast. Instead, one would write the divider as a sequential or pipelined process in which each step takes about the same amount of time as the other ALU operations. Yes, it is possible to declare multi-cycle paths, but in general, you need to be able to write the full names of the endpoints in question, which is not always easy to determine.

Ah, this is actually good intuition for me to follow while I'm learning - that it is not typical to design combinatorial paths that take longer than the target clock cycle. I was thinking that might be more common. Given that the division algorithm I was looking at occurs in iterations, it's natural to create a multi-step sequential process rather than a single long process. My primary frustration was that vivado was telling me (via get_pins) what the pins were called, yet when I tried to specify the timing constraint, it said it didn't know what those pins were :shrug:

Don't feel bad. I've been using Vivado for many years now, and I still don't understand fully how to write unambiguous timing constraints. The documentation is just awful.

You know what I noticed that lol - and I thought software documentation was bad. This doesn't answer the question I asked exactly (How to specify the constraint by name, rather than whether to at all), but it does convince me to go another route (Sequential/pipelined fast vs single slow + wait) for slower operations. Thanks for your time and advice!
